# Share OpenGraph story by shareDialog or feedDialog

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK 4.13 for iOS.

I'm successfully share custom OpenGraph story through `[FBSDKShareAPI share]`. The problem is - no dialog.

When I'm trying to share the same *context* through `FBSDKShareDialog`  - dialog appears empty and shared post neither.

Is there a possibilities to share OpenGraph stories through dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed "tune" settings for my OGOStory(*OpenGraphObjectStory*), so it'll show correctly in fine dialog. 
It's a bit confusing that in my app I have models named **story** and OGOS but, i hope, youl'll manage to understand.

```
- (void)performShareFacebookWithStory:(STLStory *)story andText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[story largeImageURL]];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImageURL:imageURL userGenerated:NO];
    NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                 @"og:type": @"stories_california:story", //OpenGraphObjectStory,
                                 @"og:title": [story title],
                                 @"og:description": [story aboutText],
                                 @"og:url": [self storyUrlForStory:story], // it's NSString
                                 @"og:image": @[photo],
                                 };
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    action.actionType = @"stories_california:story_listen";
    [action setObject:object forKey:@"story"];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"story"; //OpenGraphPreviewPropertyName

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:_parentVC
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
}
```